# Pandas applymap memory error

Tags: python, pandas, xlwings

I am trying to change all instances of datetime to a string and export my dataframe to excel. The dataframe could have between 20,000 - 50,000 entries. This is my current code:

```
wb = xw.Book('filelname.xlsx')
sht = wb.sheets['FNC']
data = wb.sheets['Data']
smdata = wb.sheets['Social']

df_sm_temp = sm_all

df_sm_temp['Date'] = df_sm_temp['Date'].apply(lambda x: str(x) if isinstance(x, datetime.time) else x)
df_sm_temp['Added'] = df_sm_temp['Added'].apply(lambda x: str(x) if isinstance(x, datetime.time) else x)
df_sm_temp['Updated'] = df_sm_temp['Updated'].apply(lambda x: str(x) if isinstance(x, datetime.time) else x)

 smdata.range('SM_ALL').value = df_sm_temp
```

When trying to run this, I get a MemoryError. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is a small sample of the data set: https://www.sendspace.com/file/jxhmx2

Thanks

Comment: Can you share a few rows of representative data so we can test and demonstrate solutions?

Comment: @jpp, Yes sure. https://www.sendspace.com/file/jxhmx2

Here is small sample of the of dataset.

Comment: Sorry, I meant can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50905695/edit) to include a few lines of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually you don't need to convert the data itself, just use `datetime_format` in conjunction with the `xlsxwriter` engine:

Demo:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('/path/to/result.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter', 
                        date_format='mm/dd/yyyy', datetime_format='mm/dd/yyyy')

df.to_excel(writer)
```